# how to filter a list using both checkboxes and radio button in jquery?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, filter, radio-button

I want to filter a list in jquery on clicking check boxes and radio button.

I am able to filter the list by clicking on either check box or radio button but i want to filter the list exactly when both the radio button as well as check box is clicked ( like e-commerce sites)

I have a list which is dynamically populated...

```
<li class="popularlist" data-count='+value.Count+' 
     data-dep_type='+value.deployment_type+' data-rate-filter='+value.Rate+' 
     data-rate='+rate+' data-id='+value.app_id+' data-app='+value.app_name+'>
 <a href="#">
    <div class="app_thumbnail">
     <img src='+value.app_logo+'>
    </div>
    <div class="app_title">'+value.app_name+'</div>
    <div class="rating">
       <span><img src='+rate+'></span>  
       <span>'+value.Count+'</span>
       <div class="clear">
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
</li>
```

and radio buttons

```
<input  type="radio" name="star1" class="chk_box" value=1 />
<input  type="radio" name="star1" class="chk_box" value=2 />
<input  type="radio" name="star1" class="chk_box" value=3 />
<input  type="radio" name="star1" class="chk_box" value=4 />
```

and check boxes

```
<input  type="checkbox" class="chk_box" />
<input  type="checkbox" class="chk_box" />
<input  type="checkbox" class="chk_box" />
```

i have used normal functions to filter the list when check box or radio button is individually clicked. need to know how to filter if both radio button and checkboxes are clicked.  please help!!

Comment: Please can you provide your "normal functions" to understand how you are currently filtering the list(s).

Comment: I hope [this](http://codepen.io/re5ive/pen/raRqGP) link helps.

Comment: Why don't your checkboxes have name or value attributes?

Comment: filtering using check box

$('ul#type').find('input:checkbox').on('click', function () {
  
   $("#mainpanel").fadeOut(500);
            $('#allapps > li').hide();
            if( $('ul#type').find('input:checked').length > 0)
            {
            $('ul#type').find('input:checked').each(function () {
                $('#allapps > li[data-dep_type='+$(this).attr('rel')).show();
            });
            }else{
    $("#mainpanel").fadeIn(500);
                $('#allapps > li').show();
            }
        });

Comment: filtering using radio buttons:

if ($('input:radio[name=star1]:checked').val()==1) {
  
 $("#mainpanel").fadeOut(500);
 $("#allapps >li").hide();
 $("#allapps >li[data-rate-filter=1]").show();
 if($('#allapps li:visible').length==0){$('#noresult').show();}
 }